# How to study the convergence of a piecewise serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I try to study the convergence of the series of the general term:
$$U_n=\begin{cases}
\frac1n ,\text{ if $n$ is square}\\
\frac1{n^2},\text{ else }
\end{cases}$$

But I didn't find a way to start, even when I read two answers I find them totally different one said that the series converges and the other said that it is a divergent one.
I didn't understand well how to solve this series.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty U_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty U_{k^2}+\sum_{\substack{k=1 \\ k\text{ non-square}}}^\infty U_k<$$$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty U_{k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}<\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand some points, why you distributed the sum while we don't sure that the two sub series converge in particular the second, how to find 2 and pi^2/3? And if you have a good reference discuss this serie please mention it, and thank you again